# An obscure autotools error with Epson iscan project

Tags: debian, compiling, debugging, autotools

I'm seeing the following error when attempting to build [iscan](https://github.com/hean01/iscan) using the master branch on Debian wheezy. 
This project provides support for Epson scanners, in cases when SANE doesn't. This project appears to be an unofficial fork of the Epson project - I'm not clear about the details. I start with:

```
faheem@orwell:/usr/local/src/iscan/iscan$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/hean01/iscan (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/hean01/iscan (push)
faheem@orwell:/usr/local/src/iscan/iscan$ git branch 
* (detached from origin/master)
  iscan-2.29.1-5
faheem@orwell:/usr/local/src/iscan/iscan$ git status
# HEAD detached at origin/master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
faheem@orwell:/usr/local/src/iscan/iscan$ debuild -uc -us
This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;
(expected one of iscan_2.29.3.orig.tar.gz, iscan_2.29.3.orig.tar.bz2,
iscan_2.29.3.orig.tar.lzma,  iscan_2.29.3.orig.tar.xz or iscan.orig)
continue anyway? (y/n)
The error is

make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/iscan/iscan'
cd . && /bin/bash /usr/local/src/iscan/iscan/missing --run aclocal-1.10 -I m4
configure.ac:273: error: unknown libltdl build type: _LTDL_TYPE
/usr/share/aclocal/ltdl.m4:226: LTDL_INIT is expanded from...
/usr/share/aclocal/ltdl.m4:352: AC_LIB_LTDL is expanded from...
configure.ac:273: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal-1.10: autom4te failed with exit status: 1
make[1]: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/iscan/iscan'
```

Suggestions for fixing or even a confirmation this can be reproduced would be helpful. I've also opened an [issue for the iscan GitHub project](https://github.com/hean01/iscan/issues/1).

Googling "configure.ac:273: error: unknown libltdl build type: _LTDL_TYPE"
brings up
http://help.lockergnome.com/linux/Beating-libtool-submission--ftopict507073.html
but the suggested

```
autoreconf -fiv
```

does not work. I might try one of the autotools mailing list, but at this point, I don't even know which one to post to. Should it be autoconf, automake, or libtool, or something else? Pointers appreciated.

Comment: ltdl is part of libtool.   Also, don't worry about matching the "273" when searching - that's just the line number in this particular configure script, not an error code.